# Splitting a string with regex ignoring the content in brackets in .net

Tags: .net, regex

I have string like `"1, 2, 3, (1, 2, (6, 7)), 4"` and want it split with regular expression in `.net` to

```
1
2
3
(1, 2, (6, 7))
4
```

In `.net` it is possible to use balanced groups, but is it possible to use it in splits and ignore content in brackets?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it important to you, to use regular expressions or may some multiline code help too?

Comment: Usually split's can use capture buffers to include the delimiter as an output element. Like split( `@"(\(...\))|,"`) as an example.

Comment: Will the parentheses always be balanced?

Comment: Have you tried a regex that isn't working, or are you just asking for a solution?

Comment: I would use Capture Collections with a regular regex match function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\([^)]*\)[^(]*\))|,
```

Try this.Though not exaclty but somewhat similar to your expected output.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/23

Comment: @mattes79 - This will not work for `1, 2, 3, (1, 2, (6, 7),(8, 9)), 4` and not for `10, 11, (12, 130)`. The list is endless.

Comment: @sln working for second case.not for first case :( http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/46

Comment: @vks - `?`. Its nothing about the regex itself, it's the OP refused to answer several questions/comments. In reality this will never work for his stated purpose.